# Using HM-10 as an iBeacon scanner, I see only a maximum of 6 iBeacons

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I have made an iBeacon scanner using the HM-10, where there may be as many as 20-30 iBeacons within range.

I connect an HM-10 (firmware V540) to my MacBook Air's USB port using the OSEPP FTDI USB-to-serial converter and a USB-mini USB cable.

Using the Arduino or CoolTerm app, I send the following AT commands:

```
AT+ROLE1
AT+IMME1
AT+RESET
AT+DISI?
```

This produces a scan of only 6 iBeacons, when I have present in the room about 30 iBeacons (all made using the HM-10 or by Kontakt).

Is this a limit in the scan firmware, or am I missing some other command?

Comment: We sent an email (English and Chinese) to the company about this.  They advised to upgrade the firmware to V544, which we did.  The limit of 6 is gone, and you can adjust the scan time from 1-9 seconds.  Last scan counted 25 iBeacons.

Comment: Can please tell what all harware you used?

Comment: @amar: the hardware used is described in the second sentence of the question. The HM-10 chip was connected directly to the OSEPP FTDI Breakout board, a USB-to-serial(TTL) converter, which in turn was connected to my MacBook Air's USB port using a USB-mini to USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

We sent an email to the company about this, in English and Chinese.  They responded with the advice to upgrade the firmware to V544.  We did this, and now the device found 25 iBeacons on the last scan.  You can also vary the scan time from 1-9 seconds.